# How to encrypt data on barcode with public and private key

Tags: javascript, c#, barcode, public-key-encryption

How could you encrypt data on a barcode with a public and private key, similar to TicketMaster's SafeTix?

Quote from [article](https://www.theage.com.au/national/victoria/new-encrypted-safetix-coming-to-melbourne-music-venues-afl-20190731-p52cht.html):

> It's a barcode that changes every 15 seconds. If you copy it, 15
>   seconds later it'll change and the copied one will no longer work

Mr Re said.

> There's two unique keys, one on the fan side and one on the scanning
>   side, and as long as they match at the time of scanning they get in.

I am looking for a suitable way to prevent fraud with ticket, and I am currently looking into making the barcode on the tickets dynamic.

Comment: sounds like the barcode is just the same as any rsa token, just displayed in barcode

Comment: Do you want C# or Javascript?

Comment: @WaiHaLee, The solution wil use C# for the backend and Javascript/Node.js for the front-end of the app. The barcodes will be generated from the backend, so this would be C# indeed.